# Pushing a list of key/value pairs in Perl Hash

Tags: perl, hash

I'm trying to 'push' a list of key/value pairs into a perl hash as follows. I thought it would work like the key-value pairs are assigned when an array is assigned to a hash. `@targets` contains tab separated strings for each elements. However for every iteration of the map loop, the hash is overwitten and at the end I only got one key-value pair in the hash which corresponds to the last element of the `@targets`. I'm trying to avoid the usual `$ID_Gene{$key}=$value` type assignments.

How to push a list as a key-value pair to the hash?

Alternatively, is there any way I can build an anonymous hash and then push that hash to the original hash?Like:  `%ID_Gene = (%ID_Gene, %AnonyHash);`

```
my %ID_Gene;
map{ %ID_Gene= (split /\t/,$_) ;
}@targets;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there, you just have the assignment in the wrong place, so you end up blowing away the entire hash each time you add an item. As a general rule, it usually doesn't make sense to do things with side-effects in `map`. You can simply do:

```
my %ID_Gene = map { split /\t/, $_ } @targets;
```

if you already have some stuff in `%ID_Gene` and you want to add to it, you can do

```
%ID_Gene = (%ID_Gene, map { split /\t/, $_ } @targets);
```

or if you think that's too much going on in one line:

```
my %to_add = map { split /\t/, $_ } @targets;
%ID_Gene = (%ID_Gene, %to_add);
```

Comment: I'm not sure I love the 2nd & 3rd solutions.  If `%ID_Gene` is large enough, re-initializing it with a list made of it's own contents might be a tad inefficient.

Comment: @tjd Agreed. I prefer `foreach my $target (@targets) { my ($k, $v) = split /\t/, $target; $ID_Gene{$k} = $v; }` for an existing hash.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot agreed, sometimes that's better, but OP specifically asked for not that solution :)

Comment: Yup, you've faithfully fulfilled OP's request for more rope, but <shudder>.  Let's hope it's used wisely.